# opengl es 2.0 etc1 powervr SGX 540

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, textures, compression

I have a problem with ETC1 textures. To load ETC1 textures I use own code that load raw data of ETC1 image, then i use GL operation to load data into GPU memory `GLES20.glCompressedTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0x8D64, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, rawSize, data);`
but when device used PowerVR SGX540 GPU, only textures with dimension 512x512 draw correctly. And i don't understand why. OpenGL ES 2.0 standard says that I can use textures with non-power of two dimensions. Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have the power of two restriction, however wrap modes and min filter are restricted. Please read the notes on http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml
which states:

> Similarly, if the width or height of a texture image are not powers of two and either the GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER is set to one of the functions that requires mipmaps or the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S or GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T is not set to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, then the texture image unit will return (R, G, B, A) = (0, 0, 0, 1).

Also I recommend you to read the answer and comments on this question: [Can OpenGL ES render textures of non base 2 dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740077/can-opengl-es-render-textures-of-non-base-2-dimensions)

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have restriction on NPOT textures, but certain GPUs do have this restriction. So you have to first check support of NPOT by presence of corresponding extension (GL_OES_texture_npot, `GL_IMG_texture_npot`).